# Is there a better way to configure EAS builds so they are easier to differentiate on the project portal?

Tags: expo, github-actions, eas

Our EAS project portal `https://expo.dev/accounts/{name}/projects/{projectName}` is really hard to decipher what is what.  Is there a better way to configure the portal so that it's easier to determine "who" pushed "what"?  When looking at this view, it's impossible to differentiate easily.

[image: Untitled.png]

For example:

- `userName` created a build in the title:

  - the `userName` is always the same.  How does this get configured?  The only time i have seen it different is if I manually kick off the build from my terminal.  However there is more than 1 user actually creating commits from GitHubActions
- `commit`

  - the commit itself isn't a link to GitHub or where the commit got generated.  And it doesn't include the commit message either, even to differentiate it.
- Subsequent builds from same branch

  - if another commit is pushed to the same branch where an existing build is running, how can I configure our GitHubActions commands to stop the current EAS build?

Answer (score 2):

#### Here's how to do it:

Convert your `app.json` to an `app.config.js` and then try code like this:

```js
const DEFAULT = {
  name: 'name',
  bundleName: 'com.name.mobile',
};

const DEV_CLIENT = {
  name: 'name-dev-client',
  bundleName: 'devclient.name.mobile',
};

const IS_DEV_CLIENT = !!process.env.IS_DEV_CLIENT;
const DEBUG_PROD = !!process.env.DEBUG_PROD;

export default {
  expo: {
    jsEngine: 'hermes',
    name: IS_DEV_CLIENT ? DEV_CLIENT.name : DEFAULT.name,
    slug: IS_DEV_CLIENT ? DEV_CLIENT.name : DEFAULT.name,
    privacy: 'hidden',
    ios: {
      supportsTablet: false,
      bundleIdentifier: IS_DEV_CLIENT
        ? DEV_CLIENT.bundleName
        : DEFAULT.bundleName,
      buildNumber: '1.0.0',
    },
    android: {
      package: IS_DEV_CLIENT ? DEV_CLIENT.bundleName : DEFAULT.bundleName,
    },
    extra: {
      eas: {
        projectId: IS_DEV_CLIENT
          ? '[your-dev-uuid]'
          : '[your-prod-uuid]',
      },
    },
  },
};
```

Note that you will probably want to exclude the `extra` field as I believe Expo will now auto-fill it. If that's not the case, you'll need to get it from the Overview page for your project.

[image]

The `extra.eas.projectId` gave me some trouble the first few builds, but once I worked that out it's been working great.

If you're using EAS, those variables will be populated dependent upon your `eas.json` config like so:

```js
    "devclient": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      },
      "ios": {
        "simulator": true
      },
      "env": {
        "IS_DEV_CLIENT": "true"
      }
    },
```